# Class differences between C++03 and C++11

Tags: c++, class, c++11

I'm current building an application in which I have a log function that is accessible in most of my classes which was declared as below:

**FileHandler.h**

```
#ifndef FILEHANDLER_H
#define FILEHANDLER_H

#pragma once

#include <SDL.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

//Include to allow logging
#include "log.h"

class fileHandler
{

    public:
        fileHandler();
        virtual ~fileHandler();

        void WriteToFile(const std::string& filename, std::string textToWrite);
        std::vector<std::string> ReadFromFile(const std::string& filename);

        std::string& TrimString(std::string& stringToTrim);


    protected:
    private:

        class log logHandler;

        std::vector<std::string> blockOfText;
        std::string currentLine;
};

#endif // FILEHANDLER_H
```

**Log.h**

```
#ifndef LOG_H
#define LOG_H

#pragma once

#include <SDL.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>

class log
{
    public:
        log();
        virtual ~log();

        void static WriteToConsole(std::string textToWrite);
        void WriteToLogFile(std::string textToWrite);

    protected:
    private:

};

#endif // LOG_H
```

This worked fine for a long time and then I wanted to include another function elsewhere in my application that was only compatible with C++11 so I told the compiler to compile to these standards. I was then receiving an error on "log logHandler" saying log is not a declared name.

I was able to resolve the problem by changing the line to

```
class log logHandler;
```

I was wondering if anybody could tell me what has changed between C++03 and C++11 that required me to do this?

EDIT: Included all relevant code to make question more complete.

Comment: At the absolute minimum, you should include in your question the contents of `log.h`!

Comment: Updated original post to include all code in filehandler.h and log.h

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't show your real code (missing `;` at the end of the class declaration, no `#endif`), but chances are that your problem is somehow related to [`std::log`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log), which has received a new overload in C++11, in combination with a `using namespace std` somewhere in your code.

Note that the new overload is probably irrelevant to the problem at hand; the real reason may very well be a change somewhere in your compiler's standard-library implementation causing an internal `#include <cmath>`. This means that even in C++03, your code was only working by sheer coincidence, and a conforming C++03 compiler was always allowed to reject it.

Here is an example program which may reproduce your problem:

```
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

struct log
{
};

int main()
{
    // log l; // does not compile
    struct log l; // compiles
}
```

Comment: A minor addition to that: if `<cmath>` is included, then `log l;` won't work even in C++03. Most likely, the standard library implementation changed so that on the OP's system, some other header is now implicitly including `<cmath>` for some reason (which is perfectly valid).

Comment: @hvd: You are right, I will add this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing has changed about how the code you posted is treated.

What I suspect is, that you *somewhere* have an

```
#include <cmath>
```

And below that, *somewhere else*

```
using namespace std;
```

This causes your compiler to not be able to unambiguously resolve the name `log`, since there is `std::log` (a function) and your class log.

By explicitly stating `class log`, you tell the compiler that you are referring to the class.